# Will cardano halving happen to increase the demand of it?

Tags: ada, money

Compared to ETH and BTC, Cardano's total supply is higher. Given this, how will ADA ever reach $1000. Will a Cardano halving happen and lead to increased demand of ADA?

Comment: I'm not sure if ADA will ever hit a thousand (less alone thousands of USD). Maybe at some point there won't be even USD? Cardano has a fixed supply of 45 billion, but it is still deflationary and just doesn't become more and more. The demand - hopefully - will be driven by utility.

Answer (score 6):

Welcome to the community.

Rewards get reduced by [up to 0.3%](https://www.reddit.com/r/cardano/comments/kr9naa/does_cardano_go_through_halving_like_bitcoin/) every epoch (5 days).

I'd suggest calculating your market cap projection. 1000 USD / current price (1.64 USD) would give us a 609.7x market cap (compared to our current market cap)

Cardano's value comes from the utility it provides, and the demand for ADA will increase with the applications built upon it, the identities managed with it, and the services governed by it. It is still, by nature, deflationary.

Answer (score 5):

No. There will be no reduction of the supply of ADA in the future to increase its value or demand. Total supply is fixed and yes its greater than that of BTC and ETH. All this means is that the individual coins are worth less themselves. You should consider the total market cap.

Consider this, is there is more Satoshies than ADA? You can always use a bigger or smaller unit. You need to look at the market cap as a whole to do a comparison.

Comment: Supply, in the context of the question refers to the rewards given out to people staking and not to the total number of ADA. So, yes, the supply will decrease. As the other answer points out, the supply of ADA set aside for rewards decreases by .3 % per epoch. So Cardano does not have halvings like bitcoin where rewards get cut once every four years but rather there is a constant, gradual decrease in rewards which result in  staking rewards four years from now  being about one half what they are today.

Answer (score 0):

There is no hidden pool of Ada, and the treasury should be used to back projects and support the growth of the ecosystem. Furthermore, to my knowledge, no new Ada are currently being minted.

Fees paid to stake-pool are charged at the point of transaction. As supply is currently constrained, it seems likely that as adoption increases and the demand for Ada increases, the price of Ada will also increase. As the cost of Ada increases, the value of the fees produced by staking will also become more valuable incentivizing more staking and a further reduction in supply, which should increase the value of Ada further. This will continue until fees are inhibiting the growth of the ecosystem and we have reached the Voltaire Era. Then, we will vote to lower fees, which will temporarily decrease the value of Ada as an appreciating asset but increase the value of Ada as a currency and Cardano as an ecosystem.